# loop through string and calculate column subtotals vb net 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a string with 1 value per line. i call it ttl_count.

ttl_count looks like this

```
1
1
1
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
0
```

etc

1's and 0's

What i want to do is run down the column of numbers in 'ttl_count' and total the consecutive groupings of 1. using the example above:

```
1
1
1 >> 3
0
0
0
1
1
1
1 >> 4
0
```

Here we see 2 consecutive groups, one with a subtotal of 3, and the other 4. i want to send each calculated subtotal into another variable to determine the MAX value and if the last entry in the variable is '1' to show the current subtotal.

not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the String.Split and String.Join Methods. Since you mentioned that you had one value per line I am assuming that you are reading from a file and have the standard windows CRLF endings. The first Split removes the line ending, I then join it back together so you have a string of just ones and zeros. I then split on the zeros which will give you an array with just ones in it. At that point it would just be as simple as using the String.Length Method on each Array element to get the Total number of ones in each string.  If you are wanting to write the information back into the source(*I am assuming a file*) will require you to iterate through the string and count the ones then append the subtotal to the existing string and write that back to a file.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim splitFirst As String() = {vbCrLf}
        Dim splitNext As String() = {"0"}
        Dim testString As String = "1" & vbCrLf &
                                   "1" & vbCrLf &
                                   "1" & vbCrLf &
                                   "0" & vbCrLf &
                                   "0" & vbCrLf &
                                   "0" & vbCrLf &
                                   "1" & vbCrLf &
                                   "1" & vbCrLf &
                                   "1" & vbCrLf &
                                   "1" & vbCrLf &
                                   "0"

        Dim results As String() = testString.Split(splitFirst, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim holding As String = String.Join("", results)
        results = holding.Split(splitNext, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        'Show the results
        For Each item In results
            Console.WriteLine(item & " Count = " & item.Length.ToString())
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Here is the same idea as a Function returning a `String Array` with the Groups of 1's as individual items.

```
Public Function getColumnCounts(data As String) As String()
    Dim splitFirst As String() = {vbCrLf} 'Seperator used to strip CrLf's
    Dim splitNext As String() = {"0"} 'Seperator used to strip the 0's
    'This is where the CrLf information is removed
    Dim results As String() = data.Split(splitFirst, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    'Join the results array to make a string
    Dim holding As String = String.Join("", results)
    'Split it again to remove the blocks of zero's leaving just groups on ones in the array
    results = holding.Split(splitNext, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    'Return the results as a String Array
    'For Example
    'For Each item In getColumnCounts(testString)
    '    Console.WriteLine(item & " Count = " & item.Length.ToString())
    'Next
    Return results
End Function
```

Comment: it works but how do i view the results? where do they go? i see the data coming in one line at a time as msgbox(item & " Count = " & item.Length.ToString()) inside the for/next loop, but how do i 'see' the result with 'Console.ReadLine()'?  Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting a MessageBox at ? This program is a simple console application that prints out each group of ones and the length. Console.Readline is just there to pause the console application so you can see what was printed to the screen, otherwise it just exits.  For the other part of your question, the results string array is where all of the information is, I just iterate through it and print each individual item and count to the console.

Comment: ok, i am using VB.NET ... now i get it. the console.read() doesnt print anything to the screen in VB.NET (2010). thanks again!